# JIT for PHP 8.1.21 will cause 503 server error

Tags: php, jit, opcache

I try to follow the [instructions here](https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/360061297593-How-to-enable-JIT-for-OPcache-in-PHP-8) to enable JIT in PHP 8.1.21

I set the JIT buffer size to 256M, as below:

```
opcache.jit_buffer_size=256M
```

I also enabled opcache.enable_cli as [this article](https://php.watch/versions/8.0/JIT) suggests me to do so

```
opcache.enable=1
opcache.enable_cli=1
```

After that, I restart PHP FPM service.

Then I check `https://www.example.com/opcache.php` and everything is correct, jit buffer size is 256MB.
And then I check `https://www.example.com/phpinfo.php` which also shows JIT is ON.

Then I visit one page on the test site, `https://www.example.com/`, I will get " 503 Service Unavailable error".

Then If I go back to `https://www.example.com/opcache.php`, I will also get 503 error.

It seems that once we try to use JIT, there will be 503 error. Why?

I check the Apache error log, and see the following:

```
[Wed Jul 19 09:40:46.504648 2023] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 5914:tid 47200906626816] [remote 79.107.70.235:1854] AH01067: Failed to read FastCGI header
[Wed Jul 19 09:40:46.504677 2023] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 5914:tid 47200906626816] (104)Connection reset by peer: [remote 79.107.70.235:1854] AH01075: Error dispatching request to :
```

**Update:**

The PHP version is 8.1.21.

**Update 2**

After upgrading to PHP 8.2.15, the error disappears. Thank you very much for all your attention and helps.

**Update 3**
After enabling JIT  in PHP 8.2.15, one of our WP site deadlocked twice for unknown reason. So we have to disable JIT again. After observing for one week, the deadlock never occurs again after JIT is disabled. So I think JIT may still not be very stable at the PHP 8.2.15.

Comment: @hakre, yes, I enable OPCache as well, not just for CLI

Comment: Check with the log of the fastgi handler/PHP, from the apache error log it is already visible that the connection was reset.

Comment: can you post the output of `php -m`, phpinfo (`php -i`) would help to pinpoint the problem... I'd guess you have some incompatible extensions (ioncube, xdebug, ...)

Comment: you say PHP8.1, but which PHP version exactly? PHP8.1.0? or 8.1.21? A lot of JIT bugs has been fixed between 8.1.0 and 8.1.21

Comment: @alancc: The exact version of your PHP FPM service you're having this issue with is still missing in your question.

Comment: @hakre, Sorry about that. Actually I have already updated the PHP version info several days ago. However, it seems the info disappears for some reason. So I update again.

Comment: @hakre It is always 8.1.21 before & after the update. The problem is still exists. I think may be I need to wait for some more time to see new updates of PHP & extension available to fix this issue.

Comment: Check with the **log of the fastgi handler/PHP**, from the apache error log it is already visible that the connection was reset. <- did you do that? You didn't provide any more log details, therefore ... perhaps that's why I had the other impression.

Comment: @hakre, Actually I have checked PHP/FPM log but does not find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using PHP<=8.1.14 and hitting PHP bug [GH-9981](https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/9981) ?!

In this case, the solution is to upgrade to PHP>=8.1.15, because that bug was fixed in PHP8.1.15. (but preferably upgrade to PHP >=8.1.21.)

Comment: I am using PHP 8.1.21 but when enable JIT > Wordpress still give me 503...

Comment: @SeCrEtBoY maybe you're hitting [GH-10914](https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/10914) ?

Comment: Just let you know that after upgrading to PHP 8.2.15, the error disappears. Thank you very much for all your attention and helps.

Comment: A follow-up, JIT in PHP 8.2.15 will cause deadlock from time to time, so I have to disable it again.